# What is transaction memo?

Tags: transactions, raw-transaction

So I'm following a library containing the file named "ProtcolConstansts.php", there's one line confusing me

```
/** @var int Maximum length of transaction memo */
public const MAX_TX_MEMO_LEN = 32; // 32 bytes
```

What is Memo in Transaction?

Comment: Which library? Are you sure it is about Ethereum?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such concept in Ethereum. Transactions don't have any "memo" feature, so it must be some custom functionality, probably in a smart contract.

My guess is that it's the length of some `bytes` variable, which is given as a parameter to a smart contract function.